# Ionic Framework - Popup cancel button doesn’t work - v1.0.0-beta.1 "actinium"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

"prompt" not close "cancel" button

On my system does not work the "Cancel" button. I did a copy paste of the original code to do a simple test and does not work.

I can not find what is wrong.

Test example: http://jsfiddle.net/Chofoteddy/y7D4r/1

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="ionic.example" ng-controller="PopupCtrl">
    <button class="button" ng-click="showPrompt()">Prompt</button>
    <pre>Response: {{response}}</pre>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular
    .module('ionic.example', ['ionic'])
    .controller('PopupCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup) {
        $scope.response = 'Hello World';
    
        $scope.showPrompt = function() {
            $ionicPopup.prompt({
                title: 'ID Check',
                subTitle: 'What is your name?'
            }).then(function(res) {
                $scope.response = res;
            });
        };
    
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a known bug for Ionic 1.0.0-beta1 https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1145

Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JAUxG/

posting code because its required:

```
angular
    .module('ionic.example', ['ionic'])
    .controller('PopupCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup) {

        $scope.showPrompt = function() {
            $ionicPopup.prompt({
                title: 'ID Check',
                subTitle: 'What is your name?'
            }).then(function(res) {
                console.log('Your name is', res);
            });
        };

    });
```

I changed the version of Ionic to the latest nightly build:
http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js

which can be found here:
http://code.ionicframework.com/#nightly